# Why is this GIF's animation speed different in Firefox vs. IE?

Tags: gif, animated

Oracle Enterprise Manager has a web interface that uses this GIF:
[image: Oracle Enterprise Manager]

The odd thing about this GIF is that in Firefox (v9&10) it spins about twice as fast as in MSIE (v7&9).

**Why does the animation speed change depending on the browser?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your GIF animation contains 40 frames, with a 0.03 second delay specified between each frame.  That should give it a nominal runtime of 1.2 seconds per loop, which matches what I'm seeing here in Firefox.

The problem seems to be that many browsers will ignore very short per-frame delays and replace them with a default delay (often 0.1 seconds).  And the cutoff for what counts as a "very short" delay varies between browsers: Firefox apparently accepts anything down to 0.02 seconds per frame, while IE ignores delays below 0.0**6** seconds per frame.

My recommendation would be to increase the per-frame delay to 0.06 seconds (and to remove every second frame if you want the animation to run fast).  That *should* give consistent speed in all major browsers.

Edit: I went and did that for you.  Here are two versions of the animation with 0.06 seconds per frame: fast (20 frames, 1.2 sec/loop) [image: Fast animation, 20 frames at 0.06 seconds / frame] and slow (40 frames, 2.4 sec/loop) [image: Fast animation, 40 frames at 0.06 seconds / frame].  I also optimized the animations with [Gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/), so they're quite a bit smaller than the original.

For more information, see:

- [Frame Delay Times for Animated GIFs](https://www.deviantart.com/humpy77/journal/Frame-Delay-Times-for-Animated-GIFs-240992090) by Steve Humphrey
- [Animated GIF Minimum Frame Delay Browser Compatibility Study](https://nullsleep.tumblr.com/post/16524517190/animated-gif-minimum-frame-delay-browser) by Jeremiah Johnson
- [Trivia: Animated GIF Timing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/trivia-animated-gif-timing) at EricLaw's IEInternals